# Permission denied when auto mount a network drive

Tags: 15.10, samba, fstab, file-sharing

Ubuntu 15.10 (fresh install)

I have set my fstab to:

```
//192.168.0.2/Music /home/pst007x/Music/ServerMusic cifs auto,credentials=/home/pst007x/.smbcredentials,defaults 0 0
```

When I start my system, the icon for the shared drive appears in Nautilus, but when I click on it I get the error:

> mount: only root can mount //192.168.0.2/Music on /home/pst007x/Music/ServerMusic

If I run:

```
sudo mount -a
```

the network drive becomes accessible, however I cannot unmount due to requiring root permissions.

```
pst007x@pst007x-Serval-Professional:~$ groups
pst007x adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
pst007x@pst007x-Serval-Professional:~$ id
uid=1000(pst007x) gid=1000(pst007x) groups=1000(pst007x),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),113(lpadmin),128(sambashare)
pst007x@pst007x-Serval-Professional:~$
```

Running DMSG, I had the following errors:

> ```
> [    6.862055] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
> [    6.862102] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
> ```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this using the following:

Terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Then adding the following:

> //192.168.0.2/Music /home/pst007x/Music/ServerMusic cifs
>   _netdev,comment=systemd.automount,auto,owner,credentials=/home/pst007x/.smbcredential,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm
>   0 0